# Публикация приложения в Google Play (подписание приложения)

Tags: android, google-play

Сделал приложение для заказчика. Для публикации в Google Play его нужно подписать и релизнуть, как я понял. Но заказчик потерял свое хранилище ключей, а я никогда не занимался публикацией в Google. Вопрос: могу ли я создать свое хранилище, создать ключ, и тд. и отправить хранилище с приложением потом заказчику?  Или как это делается? Просто при публикации у заказчика появляется ошибка несоответствия сертификатов с отпечатками SHA-1. В консоли разработчика вводится же где-то это хранилище, или как то по-другому?

Answer (score 0):

Если нету ориг ключа то залить обновление вы не сможете, только если делать новое приложение в Google Play

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Comment: Вообще-то маркет позволяет сменить ключ при каких-то условиях - спросите техподдержку или поищите в справке консоли. Чтобы не терять ключи - можно доверить их генерацию самому маркету, но тогда у вас его не будет вообще и вы не сможете публиковать приложение другим способом с той же подписью, что в гугл плей. Пердавать заказчику своё хранилище нежелательно: во-первых, вы можете оставить себе копию и как-то этим воспользоваться, во-вторых, и вам может аукнуться, если заказчик получит бан от маркета.

Comment: Я как то терял ключ, техи сказали мол выши проблемы

Comment: Я не сталкивался, но в справках написано про замену ключей: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756#upgrade . Почему не попробовать?